# $f$ normal endomorphism, then $x=y$ or $v \perp w$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f \in  \operatorname{End}(V)$ be a normal endomorphism which means that $f^* \circ f=f \circ f^*$.

Let $v,w \in V$ be eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues $x,y \in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Then $x=y$ or $v \perp w$.

$f^*$ is the adjugate and $\bar.$ is the field-automorphism and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the scalar product.

The proof in my book is:

$(x-y)\langle v,w \rangle= \langle v \bar x,w\rangle-\langle v,wy \rangle= \langle f^*(v),w\rangle-\langle v,f(w)\rangle=0$

How does $f^* \circ f=f \circ f^*$ imply that $\langle f^*(v),w\rangle=\langle v,f(w)\rangle $ (and therefore the line above equals $0$)?

Answer (score 1):

The normality does not implies this equation. The adjugate $f^*\colon V\to V$ is defined as the endomorphism such that $\langle f^*(v), w\rangle = \langle v, f(w)\rangle  $ holds for all $v,w \in V$. But, the normality of $f$ is equivalent with the fact that $f$ is (unitarily) diagonalisable, which is known as the spectral theorem.